# Showing error message after checking the back-end

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controller is something like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("Somewhere")]
    public JsonResult SetSomething(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        var successSave = this.SaveIt(propertyName,propertyValue);

        if(successSave)
            return Json(propertyValue);
        else 
           // Show a message in front end that there was problem in saving 
    }
```

And then my view is currently something like:

```
@Model.SomethingFeild
```

That just loads the value and shows it in a textbox field in there .
So how can I change this to be able to handle the psedo-code scenario I wrote in the controller, so that if something is wrong in DB ( not front-end vlaidation) such as duplicate entry, then it comes back and tells the `UI` that so `UI` shows a hard coded message?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in try catch block and add an extension method for reading exception (or your exception type that is thrown) like so:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Somewhere")]
    public JsonResult SetSomething(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        try
        {
            var successSave = this.SaveIt(propertyName, propertyValue);

            if (successSave)
                return Json(new { success = true, value = propertyValue });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Extensions.ReturnExceptionToView(ex);
        }

    }
```

Example extension method (static method):

```
internal static JsonResult ReturnExceptionToView(Exception ex)
    {
        List<object> viewErrors = new List<object>();
        viewErrors.Add(new { ErrorMessage = ex.ToString() });
        return new JsonResult() { Data = (new { success = false, errors = viewErrors }) };
    }
```

Then check for success property in the response in JS. Example below is using response of ajax call and pushing to Knockout observable array.

```
if (response.success) {
            // do something with successful response
        } else {
            // we have an error in the response.errors collection
           $.each(response.errors, function () {
                    vm.saveErrors.push(new ErrorMsg(this.ErrorMessage));
            });
```

Comment: Note: I've used a list "viewErrors" because I have joined this functionality up with validation errors (view model state, custom etc.) which returns more than one error. So that is why I have used a list in this example - you don't need to use a list if you are only ever going to have one error.